# Detect vanishing point in an image

Tags: c#, vanishing-point

In c#, is this possible to detect / find / retrieve a vanishing point ?

For example, i would like to open an image, analyse it, and on top of it, draw all the line which are pointing to the vanishing ?

I made some research, and all examples are always concerning matlab.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Kind regards.

Comment: What **is** the vanishing point?

Comment: Is it possible in C#? Of course, as long as the image is suitable. How to do it? That's too broad and otherwise off topic here.

Comment: Thanks, but do you have some link or material ?
@It'sNotALie. Vanishing point : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_point

Comment: Its not going to be easy, but this site tells you how to find it using photoshop. I will let you spend the months/years working out how to do it in code! http://www.pxleyes.com/tutorial/photoshop/1094/How-to-Find-the-Vanishing-Point-in-Any-Photo.html